# Linux ALSA snd_pcm_writei timing

Tags: linux, audio, embedded-linux, alsa

**I'm trying to play a  wav file of 1000ms in a repetitive way. So play 1000ms, then 1000ms of silence, then again 1000ms of audio ,...**

But when I print the timing during this process, I notice snd_pcm_writei() takes up some after the sound has been played and therefor is **~1600ms instead of 1000ms**. I'm using the blocking mode.

```
Play Sound:    ~1600ms
Silence:       ~1000ms
Play Sound:    ~1600ms
....
```

If I use non-blocking mode, sound is played for a very short time, a couple of ms.

Properties of wav-file:

```
RIFF (little-endian) data, WAVE audio, Microsoft PCM, 16 bit, mono 8000 Hz
```

Setup of PCM:

```
err = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_rate_resample(PCM, params, 0);
err = snd_pcm_nonblock(PCM, 0);
err = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_access(PCM, params, SND_PCM_ACCESS_RW_INTERLEAVED);
err = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_format(PCM, params, SND_PCM_FORMAT_S16_LE);
err = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_channels(PCM, params, 1);
err = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_rate_near(PCM, params, &rrate, 0);
err = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_buffer_size_near(PCM, params, &buffer_size);
err = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_period_size_near(PCM, params, &period_size, &dir);
err = snd_pcm_hw_params(PCM, params);

snd_pcm_sw_params_current(PCM, swparams);
snd_pcm_sw_params_set_start_threshold(PCM, swparams, (buffer_size / period_size) * period_size);
snd_pcm_sw_params_set_avail_min(PCM, swparams, period_event ? buffer_size : period_size);
snd_pcm_sw_params(PCM, swparams);
```

The buffer with 1000ms of audio samples is 16000 bytes, seems correct since (8000 samples / s ) * 2bytes/sample (mono + S16_LE).

To start playing the wav file, I use this piece of code:

```
qDebug() << QTime::currentTime().toString("hh:mm:ss:zzz") << " Play sound";
err = snd_pcm_writei(PCM, Buffer, 16000);
qDebug() << QTime::currentTime().toString("hh:mm:ss:zzz") << " End sound";
```

Does anyone have an explanation or tips to achieve this? Maybe a setting that's wrong or I need to use non-blocking mode.

Thanks

EDIT:

The return value or rrate is 8000, so looks good.
Here are some actual prints of the time.

```
"10:48:54:893"  Play sound 
"10:48:56:794"  End sound 
"10:48:57:802"  Play sound 
"10:48:58:913"  End sound 
"10:48:59:923"  Play sound 
"10:49:01:853"  End sound 
"10:49:02:862"  Play sound 
"10:49:04:793"  End sound 
"10:49:05:803"  Play sound 
"10:49:06:593"  End sound 
"10:49:07:602"  Play sound
```

Time between END and PLAY is around 1000ms, time between PLAY and END is between 800ms and 1900ms, so not accurate at all.

Comment: What is the value of `rrate` returned by `snd_pcm_hw_params_set_rate_near()`?

Comment: `snd_pcm_writei` accepts frames count as third parameter, not bytes.

Comment: Do you actually hear sound?
You are measuring not the time of playing, but instead time of filling the ALSA buffer.
If we assume, that ALSA buffer is 1000ms long, then first call to `snd_pcm_writei(pcm, buff, 8000) will return immediately.

Answer (score 0):

@ Геннадий Казачёк:

Yes, I always hear sound.
I first changed the length to 8000 like you suggested.
It did not really help, but is was obviously a bug.

Then I changed the buffersize and periodsize:

Before

```
snd_pcm_uframes_t buffer_size = 768;
snd_pcm_uframes_t period_size = 256;
```

After

```
snd_pcm_uframes_t buffer_size = 768*2;
snd_pcm_uframes_t period_size = 256*2;
```

I don't know why but the timings were correct after adjusting this.
Thanks for the help!